# Does torrenting expose your information more than simply browsing the clear web? Why a VPN?

Tags: vpn, security, bittorrent

Everybody says you need a VPN to torrent. I won't bother posting references because literally *everybody* says so.

Does that only apply to illegal torrenting (which I am not interested in... that's just a sick thing to do)?

If I type "what's my IP address" in Google, it'll simply give me my IP address, which means that it's no big deal whether a site which offers legitimate torrents knows my IP address, as long as it doesn't expose it publicly... Unless, of course, there's something I am missing.

I'll give a concrete example. Here's the [GIMP download link](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/). If you use Windows (or your user agent claims you use Windows), then you'll see an option for downloading the torrent version of the installer. Is downloading that torrent and putting it in a torrent client any more dangerous than hitting "download directly"? If so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, torrenting (or rather, peer-to-peer in general) does not expose any special information about your PC. However, the question is rather: to whom. With a regular HTTPS download (let’s assume encryption here), you connect to a server and ask it for the file. Only you and the server know about the contents of your connection. A man-in-the-middle attacker (not trivial by any means!) could only detect: Yup, this IP address connected to download.example.com. To check what you actually downloaded, a third party would have to retrieve the logs, if they even exist. Not realistic, unless the host is (almost) exclusively home to illegal content.

With peer-to-peer, anyone can participate in your download. They don’t even need to do a man-in-the-middle attack. Just check which IP addresses are downloading the latest Metallica album torrent right now and then sue everyone (or something the like).

In most peer-to-peer networks, your download also involves you uploading to others. Legally, this is a critical distinction. If you’re downloading, that may also be illegal. However, you’re only creating a copy for yourself. If you’re uploading, you’re making it illegally available for others, so the copyright holder can multiply the already imaginary damages by *$HUGE_NUMBER* and then sue for that. Nice.

If you’re not downloading/uploading anything illegal, there’s nothing to fear. Well, your ISP may or may not be unhappy with peer-to-peer activity. I’m downloading most Linux stuff using torrents, if possible. I also leave it running (seeding) for a few months or years. Torrents have a slight advantage over regular downloads: built-in integrity verification.

Answer (score 2):

Using a VPN while torrenting is chiefly for covering your actions from your
ISP (and perhaps your government).

For some people it is mandatory, as some ISPs will block torrents.
Evidently, this is not your case.

Torrenting itself is not dangerous in any manner, but has some advantages
and disadvantages.

The advantages are that downloads can be stopped and restarted at will,
and if several sources are available then it may use better your
entire bandwidth.

The disadvantages are that you may have to wait for the sources to accept
your connection, and they might be too slow.

In general, if you have fast internet, then a direct download that
takes some minutes is less hassle than going through a torrent client.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of 'torrent sites' that list torrents (and provide links to them) have very prominent annoying scary ads from VPN companies saying that you absolutely must use a VPN when torrenting. This is not true for many people. In my country (UK) most ISPs block access to these torrent list sites (the Pirate Bay is a famous one but there are others). However, you can use Tor Browser to get at the sites and copy the link into a torrent client like Transmission, Deluge, uTorrent, etc. When using Tor Browser which is a modified version of Firefox, it is a good idea to install ad and pop up blockers because a lot of those sites will send a blizzard of popups, adware links, etc, when you first click to search (or anywhere else). You run the risk that agents of copyright owners collect the IP address of everyone sharing files that they want to track. The worst that you can usually expect in my country is a letter from your ISP saying 'you shouldn't do this'.